# Как в code blocks отключить предложения по автодополнению кода?

Tags: c++

Начинаю писать код в code blocks на mac os и после написания любой строки появляется этот серый прямоугольник.
Даже если закрыть приложения и снова открыть, то проблема остается.
Как отключить дополнение кода?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

В меню Settings->Editor уберите галочки с
"Code Completion", "Documentation popup", а в выпадающем списке "Tooltips" выберите "none". Возможно, для решения Вашей проблемы достаточно будет только последнего (про всплывающие подсказки).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]